# is it possible to evil twin a WPA 2 Wifi using one of EAP methods?

Tags: wifi, wpa2, social-engineering, wpa2-eap, evil-twin

the same as [fluxion](https://github.com/FluxionNetwork/fluxion)  but without the captive portal just like this video

[Stealing 802.1x Credentials with Rogue AP & RADIUS server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoihKhQWZ7)
he was able to get the username and the password of an EAP wifi without cracking just by launching  an rouge AP

if it's possible which inner type would it be !

Answer (score 2):

This is possible whenever there's an authentication server involved and the client doesn't validate the authentication server's certificate (or the user manually accepts such a certificate).

However, this is not possible on *pre-shared key* WPA2-PSK networks, because in IEEE 802.11i *four-way handshake* both the AP and the client prove to each other knowing the key without disclosing it. The username and the password are not revealed during the WPA2 authentication, but during the 802.1x authentication.

Because WPA2-PSK has other problems (everyone who knows the PSK is able to decrypt traffic of all other users), WPA2-Enterprise with validation of the authentication server's certificate is recommended.

Comment: "this is not possible on pre-shared key WPA2-PSK networks, because in IEEE 802.11i four-way handshake "

i meant tricking the user to enter his wpa2 psk on an rouge EAP with the same name ....
"This is possible" 
....
"if it's possible which inner type would it be !"
what is the inner type that would make the attack  success ?!

Comment: There's no inner type on PSK, and with WPA2-Enterprise it could be any that requires username and password based authentication.  Did I get it right that you plan to create a rogue AP that asks WPA2-Enterprise username and password and hope the user will enter the PSK key as the password? That could actually work, but it requires user interaction just like the captive portal approach.

Comment: "but it requires user interaction just like the captive portal approach"

but at least it's faster than the captive portal process 
"There's no inner type on PSK"
the inner type that it's been used in the video that receives the username and the password in plaintext ....!!!